# when click on one, other menu items on bottom disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my website http://poltr.com/

[image]
[image]

when click on one, other menu items on bottom disappears. screen1 is the original, screen 2 is when i clicked on it, It happens on mobile window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following css:

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-menu {
    position: relative !important;
    width:100%;
  }
}
```